# Create a unit test for a function directly (not part of a class, struct or protocol)

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

Currently we have a function that isn't part of a class, struct or protocol.  I know typically you need a SUT to unit test, something like:

```
var sut: ToDoStorgeManager!

    func test_create_todo() {

        //Given the name & status
        let name = "Todo1"
        let finished = false

        //When add todo
        let todo = sut.insertTodoItem(name: name, finished: finished)

        //Assert: return todo item
        XCTAssertNotNil( todo )

    }
```

But since its only a function there isn't a SUT to test.  Is there a way to unit test the function directly?

Comment: How is the function defined?  If it is just a global function then just call it, but *why* is it a global function?

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm thinking of just putting them all in a manager class and using the manager class as SUT

Comment: IDK what your understanding of what a `SUT` is, but there is absolutely no requirement that "unit tests can only test types". You can test functions, operators, heck, even the value of constants

Comment: @SwiftyJD You can do that, but if you have some sort of miscellaneous class that simply collects a range of unrelated functions that suggests to me  that  you need to re-think your object design.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't call the function? Like is there an error?